# Метод оценки вероятности N-граммы

Tags: java, c++, массивы, математика

Сама задача: 
Под N-граммой понимается последовательность из N слов. При решении можно считать, что все слова пронумерованы, и работать с последовательностью из N целых чисел.

***Задача обучения:***
Пусть имеется последовательность X = {x(i)}, где i - индекс(i = 1..T). Данный набор, как правило, называют набором обучающих данных.
Необходимо вычислить и запомнить вероятности вхождения для любой подпоследовательности из N подряд идущих значений p(x(i), x(i+1), .., x(i+N)) = c(x(i), x(i+1), .., x(i+N)) / T - N, где c(x(i), x(i+1), .., x(i+N)) - количество встреч подпоследовательности x(i), x(i+1), .., x(i+N) в X.
***Вычисление вероятности для N-граммы:***
Для последовательности чисел y(i), y(i+1), .., y(i+N) необходимо вернуть вероятность ее встречи в последовательности X - p(x(i), x(i+1), .., x(i+N)).
С задачей обучения всё более-менее ясно, а вот с вычислением вероятности для N-граммы не совсем. Что за числа эти y(i), y(i+1), .., y(i+N)?  произвольные числа? когда числа x(i+1), .., x(i+N) в X это числа, которые должны обязательно входить в X? А что такое X - p(x(i), x(i+1), .., x(i+N))??? Когда X-множество, а p(x(i), x(i+1), .., x(i+N)) - число.И как для этого считать вероятность вхождения чисел y(i), y(i+1), .., y(i+N)??
Кто может, объясните по подробнее пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, вот вам пример, может, так будет понятнее

Допустим, у вас последовательность нулей и единиц:

```
X = 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

и N = 4. Тогда у нас есть такие 4-подпоследовательности:

```
X = 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
   [1 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 1]
       [0 0 1 0]
         [0 1 0 0]
           [1 0 0 0]
```

Получаются вероятности по данной вам формуле:

```
p([1 0 0 0]) = 2 / 5 = 0.4
p([0 0 0 1]) = 1 / 5 = 0.2
p([0 0 1 0]) = 1 / 5 = 0.2
p([0 1 0 0]) = 1 / 5 = 0.2
```

Дальше, нам надо вычислить вероятность для какой-нибудь последовательности `[y1 y2 y3 y4]`. Если `[y1 y2 y3 y4]` встречается в нашем списке, вероятность у нас уже посчитана (например, если `[y1 y2 y3 y4] = [0 0 0 1]`, вероятность равна 0.2). Если нет, вероятность будет, судя по всему, 0.

Comment: А почему при N = 4 именно такие подпоследовательности?
Вы отбросили те случаи, при которых кол-во вхождений в последовательность равно 0?

Comment: @rekrut: я просто выбрал подпоследовательности заданной последовательности X.

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо и на этом!!!